# How to resolve syntax errors in this RSA implementation using Verilog?

Tags: verilog, fpga, xilinx

I am trying to implement RSA on and virtex 5 FPGA using verilog. Xilinx ISE logs aren't very descriptive. I'm using a CORDIC 4.0 IP core and a Random number generator. I've been working on this for the past week and I can't seem to get it straight.

**MAIN FILE**

```
`include "GARO.v"


module RSA_Encryption(RST_N,CLOCK,CTEXTPUB,RANDP,RANDQ,RANDE,PRIME_CHECK,PRIME_CHECKED,MESSAGE,RECEIVED);

//******************************************************
//Declarations
//******************************************************

reg RST_N;
input wire CLOCK;
input wire [31:0] PRIME_CHECKED;
output wire [31:0] PRIME_CHECK;
input wire [31:0] RANDP;
input wire [31:0] RANDQ;
input wire [31:0] RANDE;
integer randp;
integer randq;
integer phi;
integer e;
integer d;
integer  mod = 0;
integer i = 0;
input wire [31:0] MESSAGE;
input wire [31:0] RECEIVED;
integer message;
integer received;
integer sqroot;

output wire [31:0] CTEXTPUB;

RST_N = 1;
d = 1;
//******************************************************





//******************************************************
//Calling random number generator module to get random numbers via wires: RANDP, RANDQ and RANDE
//******************************************************

fibonacci_lfsr_nbit(CLOCK,RST_N,RANDP);
fibonacci_lfsr_nbit(CLOCK,RST_N,RANDQ);
fibonacci_lfsr_nbit(CLOCK,RST_N,RANDE);

//******************************************************




//******************************************************
//Assigning random numbers from respective wires to integer variables randp, randq and e
//******************************************************

e = RANDE;
randp = RANDP;
randq = RANDQ;

//******************************************************




//******************************************************
//Check whether randp is prime or not
//******************************************************
do begin
    Square_Root_CORDIC_Core_IP (CLOCK,sqroot,randp);
    for(i = 0 ; i <= sqroot ; i++)
    begin
        if((sqroot%i) == 0)
        begin
            break;
        end
    end
    break;
    randp = RANDP;
end while(1);

//******************************************************





//******************************************************
//Check whether randq is prime or not
//******************************************************
do begin
    Square_Root_CORDIC_Core_IP (CLOCK,sqroot,randq);
    for(int i = 0;i<=sqroot,i++)
    begin
        if((sqroot%i) == 0)
        begin
            break;
        end
    end
    break;
    randq = RANDQ;
end while(1);

//*******************************************************






//*******************************************************
//Computing 'phi'
//*******************************************************

phi = (randp-1)(randq-1);

//*******************************************************







//*******************************************************
//Selecting 'e'
//*******************************************************

do begin
    e = RANDE;
end while(e < phi && e > 1);

//*******************************************************






//*******************************************************
//Checking if gcd(e,phi) is 1   
//*******************************************************

do begin
    rem = phi%e;

    if(rem == 0 && e == 1)
    begin
        break;
    end

    else
    begin
        do begin
            e = RANDE;
        end while(e > phi && e > 1);
    end

    phi = e;
    e = rem;
end while(1);

//***********************************************






//***********************************************
//Computing 'n'
//***********************************************

n = randp*randq;

//***********************************************






//***********************************************
//Calculating 'd'
//***********************************************

do begin
    mod = (d*e)%phi;
    d = d+1;
end while(mod != 1);

//***********************************************






//***********************************************
//Computing Ciphertext using public key i.e (n,e)
//***********************************************

message = MESSAGE;
do begin
    message = message*message;
    e--;
end while(e != 0);

CTEXTPUB = message%n;

//***********************************************








//***********************************************
//Decrypting ciphertext using private key i.e (n,d)
//***********************************************

received = RECEIVED;
do begin

    received = received*received;
    d = d-1;

end while (d != 0);

received = received%n;

//************************************************

endmodule
```

**RANDOM NUMBER GENERATOR**

```
module fibonacci_lfsr_nbit
   #(parameter BITS = 32)
   (
    input             clk,
    input             rst_n,

    output reg [31:0] data
    );

   reg [31:0] data_next;
   always_comb begin
      data_next = data;
      repeat(BITS) begin
         data_next = {(data_next[31]^data_next[1]), data_next[31:1]};
      end
   end

   always_ff @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n) begin
      if(!rst_n)
         data <= 32'h1f1f;
      else
         data <= data_next;
      end
   end

endmodule
```

**HERE'S THE IP CORE API**

```
`timescale 1 ns/1 ps

module Square_Root_CORDIC_Core_IP (
  clk, x_out, x_in
)/* synthesis syn_black_box syn_noprune=1 */;
  input clk;
  output [31 : 0] x_out;
  input [31 : 0] x_in;
```

**LOGS**

```
Started : "Behavioral Check Syntax".
Determining files marked for global include in the design...
Running vlogcomp...
Command Line: vlogcomp -work isim_temp -intstyle ise -prj G:/Xilinx_Projects/first_project/RSA/RSA_Encryption_stx_beh.prj
Determining compilation order of HDL files
Analyzing Verilog file "G:/Xilinx_Projects/first_project/RSA/RSA_Encryption.v" into library isim_temp
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "GARO.v" Line 11: Syntax error near "begin".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:525 - "GARO.v" Line 14: Inconsistent dimension in declaration
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "GARO.v" Line 14: Syntax error near "}".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:598 - "GARO.v" Line 1: Module <fibonacci_lfsr_nbit> ignored due to previous errors.
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "G:/Xilinx_Projects/first_project/RSA/RSA_Encryption.v" Line 32: Syntax error near "=".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "G:/Xilinx_Projects/first_project/RSA/RSA_Encryption.v" Line 57: Syntax error near "=".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "G:/Xilinx_Projects/first_project/RSA/RSA_Encryption.v" Line 70: Syntax error near ")".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "G:/Xilinx_Projects/first_project/RSA/RSA_Encryption.v" Line 71: Syntax error near "+".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "G:/Xilinx_Projects/first_project/RSA/RSA_Encryption.v" Line 75: Syntax error near ";".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "G:/Xilinx_Projects/first_project/RSA/RSA_Encryption.v" Line 78: Syntax error near ";".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "G:/Xilinx_Projects/first_project/RSA/RSA_Encryption.v" Line 92: Syntax error near ")".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "G:/Xilinx_Projects/first_project/RSA/RSA_Encryption.v" Line 93: Syntax error near "i".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "G:/Xilinx_Projects/first_project/RSA/RSA_Encryption.v" Line 149: Syntax error near ";".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "G:/Xilinx_Projects/first_project/RSA/RSA_Encryption.v" Line 154: Syntax error near "begin".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:53 - "G:/Xilinx_Projects/first_project/RSA/RSA_Encryption.v" Line 4: <RST_N> is not a port.
ERROR:HDLCompiler:1059 - "G:/Xilinx_Projects/first_project/RSA/RSA_Encryption.v" Line 230: d is an unknown type
ERROR:HDLCompiler:1059 - "G:/Xilinx_Projects/first_project/RSA/RSA_Encryption.v" Line 232: received is an unknown type
ERROR:HDLCompiler:598 - "G:/Xilinx_Projects/first_project/RSA/RSA_Encryption.v" Line 4: Module <RSA_Encryption> ignored due to previous errors.
Verilog file G:/Xilinx_Projects/first_project/RSA/RSA_Encryption.v ignored due to errors

Process "Behavioral Check Syntax" failed

Process "Behavioral Check Syntax" failed
```

Comment: Really, you want help in fixing syntax errors? Has your code ever even simulated?

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of things wrong here.

The most important problem, though, is that you are trying to write Verilog code as if it's a procedural programming language. This won't work; Verilog is a hardware description language. You cannot use constructs like `for` and `while` loops to implement iteration in hardware; these operations must be implemented as clocked logic.

Get a good textbook on FPGA design and work through it. You have a lot to learn.

If this is coursework: contact your professor or a teaching assistant **now**. You are not going to make your deadline.